# why do i get No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: sql-server, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string

I am using a WCF service with my MVC application, I am having this problem because i have a new computer with a new sql server installation. I am trying to adjust my Web.Config to match my new sql instance.

I am not sure why i get No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. but I think it is to do with the fact that my ConnectionString source may not be correct. I have tried using "." and also "(local)" but it doesnt seem to work.

**Connection string sample**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="InventoryManagerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/InventoryManagerModel.csdl|res://*/InventoryManagerModel.ssdl|res://*/InventoryManagerModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=InventoryManager;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Sql Server**

[image]

Comment: Did you try with SQL server authentication ?

Comment: no just windows authentication @Shyju

Comment: Is SQL running on the standard port? "1433"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was a connection string issue, instead of using just "." I had to use my machine name only without the account name.